# Как добавить временную пометку для выполненной команды?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как задать коду временное значение, чтобы последующее выполнение команд проверялось этим временным значением?

Например, были внесены значения в реестр, сделать пометку, следующая команда выполняется с проверкой этой пометки. Затем создается еще одна пометка и выполняется следующая команда, так же, с проверкой предыдущей пометки.

Дело в том, что при изменении нескольких ключей реестра все их быстро не проверить (придется писать кучу строк для проверки всех веток и ключей), поэтому нужно дать следующей команде знать, что код выполнен и можно приступать к следующим задачам.

```
if (args.Any())
{
    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("MyAapp\\BranchReg", true);
    key.DeleteValue("KeyReg", false);
    key.Close();
    // сделать пометку №1
    if (пометка №1)
    {
        Process.Start(args[0]);
        // сделать пометку №2
        if (пометка №2)
        {
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("MyAapp\\BranchReg");
            key.SetValue("KeyReg", "");
            key.Close();

            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Подробнее по коду - переносим файл на приложение, получаем аргументы от файла, далее выполняется команда удаления значений в реестре, чтобы их не проверять и не считывать километры кода, ставим пометку, что код выше выполнился. Создаем условие, что если была установлена пометка №1 то разрешено запустить файл. Когда файл запускается, приложение должно прочитать следующую строчку кода с пометкой №2 и следующим условием понять, что файл был запущен, и теперь разрешено вернуть значения реестра.

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса

Comment: Организуйте очередь команд и выполняйте в порядке поступления. стандартных классов Queue или ConcurrentQueue более чем достаточно для этого. Но вопрос действительно непонятен, опишите подробнее.

Comment: Добавил описание к коду.

Comment: "чтобы ... не считывать километры кода" - для этого изобрели классы и функции

Comment: больше идей нет, основываясь на текущем описании, только https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC поможет. стоит подробнее расписать, что к чему

Comment: мне кажется вы забыли, что ваша программа будет работать не в однозадачной, а во вполне себе многозадачной среде и данные реестра могут быть изменены кем-то еще, независимо от вашей программы, а вы получите некорректные данные или исключение. Так что если вы работаете с разделяемыми ресурсами, а реестр и файлы таковыми являются, то экономить на проверках состояния перед выполнением операции себе дороже.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно но.

Делаем статический класс с метками, он будет виден из любой точки кода.
Если нужно, чтобы актуальность меток сохранялась при перезапуске приложения:
храните их в настройках приложения.

```
static class Marks{
  internal static bool PrimeraMark=false;
  internal static bool SegundoMark=false;
  internal static bool TerceraaMark=false;
} 
if (args.Any())
{
    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("MyAapp\\BranchReg", true);
    key.DeleteValue("KeyReg", false);
    key.Close();
    Marks.PrimeraMark=true;
    if (Marks.PrimeraMark)
    {
        Process.Start(args[0]);
        // сделать пометку №2
        Marks.SegundoMark=true;
        if (Marks.SegundoMark)
        {
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("MyAapp\\BranchReg");
            key.SetValue("KeyReg", "");
            key.Close();

            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это нонсенс. Присвоение булевской переменной значения `true` и проверка этой переменной в следующей строчке - какой результат этой проверки Вы ожидаете получить?